# Android setDisplayOrientation

Tags: android, camera, rotation

I've done my fair share of research, and I've even used the method suggested by the official Android API, but nothing seems to work.

I am running a QR code scanner app using the ZBar library, and I seem to be permanently stuck on one orientation mode: portrait. And only a specific portrait too; if I try to flip my tablet 180 degrees, the resulting camera display is upside-down. When in landscape, the display is on its side, both pointing toward where the original portrait mode.

The code I use is as following:

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();

     int degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
 }
```

Which is suggested by the Google API. But nothing works; .setDisplayOrientation() does nothing. Anyone have similar issues?

Comment: the problem is while taking a picture or loading it?

Comment: Neither, when I'm displaying the preview. I can hold anything up at the camera and it displays it as on its side.